# How to use @property in raw sql or add alias for the django ORM query

Tags: sql, django, python-2.7, django-models

I used SQL query like this:

```
        SELECT ns.id, ns.title, ns.image, 
               ns.briefDescr as description, ns.url, 
               um.team_id as team
        FROM app_news ns
          INNER JOIN app_news_teams nsts
            ON ns.id = nsts.news_id
          INNER JOIN app_userteam um
            ON nsts.team_id = um.team_id
        WHERE um.user_id = %s AND ns.isActive = 1 GROUP BY ns.id
        ORDER BY ns.id DESC
```

But I need to add some more logic for the field 'image', I decided to use decorator @property to the model:

```
@property
def image(self):
    '''some logic here'''
    return self._image
```

But now sql code doesn't work. Also I tried annotation to add 'um.team_id as team'. Could you please give me some idea have can I use @property and save the current structure of sql response (id, title, image, url, description and team)?

Edit:
1)I run query in the view as raw query.

```
articles = News.objects.raw(sql, [sid, ])
```

As the result I want to execute sql query or orm query and save current structure of response but with the function field 'image'

2)When I run this sql I have an exception "ns.image" doesn't exist

```
# model before
class News(models.Model):
"""other fields """
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/news', blank=True)

# model now
class News(models.Model):
"""other fields """
    _image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/news', blank=True)

    @property
    def image(self):
        """some logic here"""
        return self._image
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Where is your sql query executed? How come adding `@property` affects the query? Unless you point that out, they are just two completely different things to me.

Comment: I added more details to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not possible to use sql and not orm query with the @property. TO save the same structure of response I changed the model by adding needed values using @property for e.g.:

```
@property
def team(self):
    # get team...
    return team
```